# Как добавить в название файла функцию time()

Tags: php, файлы

При загрузки файла на сервер, нужно дописать к названию файла уникальный номер например через функцию time() но не знаю как??
ниже код

```html
<?php

if( isset( $_POST['my_file_upload'] ) ){  
    // ВАЖНО! тут должны быть все проверки безопасности передавемых файлов и вывести ошибки если нужно

    $uploaddir = '../../../uploads'; // . - текущая папка где находится submit.php
    
    // cоздадим папку если её нет
    if( ! is_dir( $uploaddir ) ) mkdir( $uploaddir, 0777 );

    $files      = $_FILES; // полученные файлы
    $done_files = array();

    // переместим файлы из временной директории в указанную
    foreach( $files as $file ){
        $file_name = cyrillic_translit( $file['name'] );

        if( move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], "$uploaddir/$file_name" ) ){
            $done_files[] = realpath( "$uploaddir/$file_name" );
        }
    }
    
    $data = $done_files ? array('files' => $done_files ) : array('error' => 'Ошибка загрузки файлов.');
    
    die( json_encode( $data ) );
}


## Транслитирация кирилических символов
function cyrillic_translit( $title ){
    $iso9_table = array(
        'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V', 'Г' => 'G', 'Ѓ' => 'G',
        'Ґ' => 'G', 'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E', 'Ё' => 'YO', 'Є' => 'YE',
        'Ж' => 'ZH', 'З' => 'Z', 'Ѕ' => 'Z', 'И' => 'I', 'Й' => 'J',
        'Ј' => 'J', 'І' => 'I', 'Ї' => 'YI', 'К' => 'K', 'Ќ' => 'K',
        'Л' => 'L', 'Љ' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N', 'Њ' => 'N',
        'О' => 'O', 'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R', 'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T',
        'У' => 'U', 'Ў' => 'U', 'Ф' => 'F', 'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'TS',
        'Ч' => 'CH', 'Џ' => 'DH', 'Ш' => 'SH', 'Щ' => 'SHH', 'Ъ' => '',
        'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ь' => '', 'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'YU', 'Я' => 'YA',
        'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'ѓ' => 'g',
        'ґ' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'yo', 'є' => 'ye',
        'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'ѕ' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'j',
        'ј' => 'j', 'і' => 'i', 'ї' => 'yi', 'к' => 'k', 'ќ' => 'k',
        'л' => 'l', 'љ' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'њ' => 'n',
        'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's', 'т' => 't',
        'у' => 'u', 'ў' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'ts',
        'ч' => 'ch', 'џ' => 'dh', 'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'shh', 'ъ' => '',
        'ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya'
    );
    $name = strtr( $title, $iso9_table);
    $name = preg_replace('~[^A-Za-z0-9\'_\-\.]~', '-', $name );
    $name = preg_replace('~\-+~', '-', $name ); // --- на -
    $name = preg_replace('~^-+|-+$~', '', $name ); // кил - на концах
    return $name;
}
```

Comment: `return $name.time()` ? или лучше `$filename .= time()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

if( isset( $_POST['my_file_upload'] ) ){  
    // ВАЖНО! тут должны быть все проверки безопасности передавемых файлов и вывести ошибки если нужно

    $uploaddir = '../../../uploads'; // . - текущая папка где находится submit.php

    // cоздадим папку если её нет
    if( ! is_dir( $uploaddir ) ) mkdir( $uploaddir, 0777 );

    $files      = $_FILES; // полученные файлы
    $done_files = array();

    // переместим файлы из временной директории в указанную
    foreach( $files as $file ){
        $file_name = cyrillic_translit( $file['name'] );

        ////START////
        $pathinfo = pathinfo($file_name);
        $file_name = $pathinfo['filename'].'_'.time();
        //$file_name = $pathinfo['filename'].'_'.md5(mtime());//Я бы сделал так
        $file_name .= '.'.$pathinfo['extension'];
        $file_name = strtolower($file_name);
        ////END////

        if( move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], "$uploaddir/$file_name" ) ){
            $done_files[] = realpath( "$uploaddir/$file_name" );
        }
    }

    $data = $done_files ? array('files' => $done_files ) : array('error' => 'Ошибка загрузки файлов.');

    die( json_encode( $data ) );
}


## Транслитирация кирилических символов
function cyrillic_translit( $title ){
    $iso9_table = array(
        'А' => 'A', 'Б' => 'B', 'В' => 'V', 'Г' => 'G', 'Ѓ' => 'G',
        'Ґ' => 'G', 'Д' => 'D', 'Е' => 'E', 'Ё' => 'YO', 'Є' => 'YE',
        'Ж' => 'ZH', 'З' => 'Z', 'Ѕ' => 'Z', 'И' => 'I', 'Й' => 'J',
        'Ј' => 'J', 'І' => 'I', 'Ї' => 'YI', 'К' => 'K', 'Ќ' => 'K',
        'Л' => 'L', 'Љ' => 'L', 'М' => 'M', 'Н' => 'N', 'Њ' => 'N',
        'О' => 'O', 'П' => 'P', 'Р' => 'R', 'С' => 'S', 'Т' => 'T',
        'У' => 'U', 'Ў' => 'U', 'Ф' => 'F', 'Х' => 'H', 'Ц' => 'TS',
        'Ч' => 'CH', 'Џ' => 'DH', 'Ш' => 'SH', 'Щ' => 'SHH', 'Ъ' => '',
        'Ы' => 'Y', 'Ь' => '', 'Э' => 'E', 'Ю' => 'YU', 'Я' => 'YA',
        'а' => 'a', 'б' => 'b', 'в' => 'v', 'г' => 'g', 'ѓ' => 'g',
        'ґ' => 'g', 'д' => 'd', 'е' => 'e', 'ё' => 'yo', 'є' => 'ye',
        'ж' => 'zh', 'з' => 'z', 'ѕ' => 'z', 'и' => 'i', 'й' => 'j',
        'ј' => 'j', 'і' => 'i', 'ї' => 'yi', 'к' => 'k', 'ќ' => 'k',
        'л' => 'l', 'љ' => 'l', 'м' => 'm', 'н' => 'n', 'њ' => 'n',
        'о' => 'o', 'п' => 'p', 'р' => 'r', 'с' => 's', 'т' => 't',
        'у' => 'u', 'ў' => 'u', 'ф' => 'f', 'х' => 'h', 'ц' => 'ts',
        'ч' => 'ch', 'џ' => 'dh', 'ш' => 'sh', 'щ' => 'shh', 'ъ' => '',
        'ы' => 'y', 'ь' => '', 'э' => 'e', 'ю' => 'yu', 'я' => 'ya'
    );
    $name = strtr( $title, $iso9_table);
    $name = preg_replace('~[^A-Za-z0-9\'_\-\.]~', '-', $name );
    $name = preg_replace('~\-+~', '-', $name ); // --- на -
    $name = preg_replace('~^-+|-+$~', '', $name ); // кил - на концах
    return $name;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что надо!

Answer (score 0):

Для генерации уникального значения можно воспользоваться дополнительными уникальными данными, например если вы позволяете загружать данные, только авторизированным пользователям, можно использовать id пользователя или время регистрации.

Если вы хотите вставлять уникальное значение ИМЕННО в название файла (file_name%UNIQ_NUM%.exe), то перед этим парсите имя файла.

Само же уникально число можно создать так:

```
mr_rand(0,time()+$uniqValue) //or
mr_rand(0,microtime()+$uniqValue)
```

В `$uniqValue`, нужно положить какое-то уникально значение, например как id пользователя или размер файла или id пользователя + id файла

Хотя использовать размер файла не очень хорошо

PS
Хочу отметить, что данный метод генерации из под VM не стоит использовать.

PSPS
Прочитайте про [PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/)

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach( $files as $file ){
        $file_name = cyrillic_translit( $file['name'] );

        // меняем имя файла до тех пор, пока существует файл с аналогичным названием           
        do {
            $file_info = pathinfo($file_name); 
            $realName = $file_info['filename'] . rand(0,99);
            $file_name = $realName . "." . $file_info["extension"]; 
        } while ( file_exists( "$uploaddir/$file_name" ) )

        if( move_uploaded_file( $file['tmp_name'], "$uploaddir/$file_name" ) ){
            $done_files[] = realpath( "$uploaddir/$file_name" );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ну хоть узнал про функцию pathinfo после того, как увидел дизлайки :)